# Implementing memcmp

Tags: c++, c, memcmp

The following is the Microsoft CRT implementation of memcmp:

```
int memcmp(const void* buf1,
           const void* buf2,
           size_t count)
{
    if(!count)
        return(0);

    while(--count && *(char*)buf1 == *(char*)buf2 ) {
        buf1 = (char*)buf1 + 1;
        buf2 = (char*)buf2 + 1;
    }

    return(*((unsigned char*)buf1) - *((unsigned char*)buf2));
}
```

It basically performs a byte by byte comparision.

My question is in two parts:

1. Is there any reason to not alter this to an int by int comparison until `count  < sizeof(int)`, then do a byte by byte comparision for what remains?
2. If I were to do 1, are there any potential/obvious problems?

Notes: I'm not using the CRT at all, so I have to implement this function anyway. I'm just looking for advice on how to implement it correctly.

Comment: This isn't quite true for the most part. Assuming you compile with optimizations on, it's going to turn into a compiler intrinsic, rather than call the CRT's implementation.

Comment: Added in the C tag as this is really a C question

Comment: When optimizing, one question to think about is *how large of a data size is needed before any significant improvement is seen?*  Sometimes the overhead of executing the function takes up more time than the actual comparison.

Comment: Is this really the implementation? I would have thought they're using SIMD instructions (SSE).

Answer (score 8):

You could do it as an int-by-int comparison or an even wider data type if you wish.

The two things you have to watch out for (at a minimum) are an overhang at the *start* as well as the end, and whether the alignments are different between the two areas.

Some processors run slower if you access values without following their alignment rules (some even crash if you try it).

So your code could probably do `char` comparisons up to an `int` alignment area, then `int` comparisons, then `char` comparisons again but, again, the alignments of *both* areas will probably matter.

Whether that extra code complexity is worth whatever savings you will get depends on many factors outside your control. A possible method would be to detect the ideal case where both areas are aligned identically and do it a fast way, otherwise just do it character by character.

Comment: Wouldn't that optimization also require that *both* pointers overhang at the start by the same amount.

Comment: That optimisation is possible but I suspect that with all the casting that would be involved (to `uintptr_t` from void for alignment check, to `int*` for comparisons and `char*`...) it would be quicker to just drop down to assembly and hack it together...

Answer (score 6):

The optimization you propose is very common. The biggest concern would be if you try to run it on a processor that doesn't allow unaligned accesses for anything other than a single byte, or is slower in that mode; the x86 family doesn't have that problem.

It's also more complicated, and thus more likely to contain a bug.

Comment: Aligned access of _both_ pointers is required for performance (especially when using 128-bit sse). See [Importance of alignment even on x86 machines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/27/221486.aspx) (admittedly from 2004, but should give you some idea of the luriking terrors).

Comment: @bobbogo: misaligned SSE access is *much* faster on modern Intel processors than it was in 2004; aligned access should still be preferred when possible, but I have seen many situations where misaligned access was faster than aligned access + software fixup.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: Yeah, YMMV as usual. Presumably for small areas it doesn't really matter how inefficient you are. Is there a limit on the memory block size where aligned access + software fixup bcomes faster than without the fixup on the newest CPUs?

Comment: @bobbogo: Not really, no.  There are certain highly specific scenarios where it's faster, but in general, unaligned SSE access (even when it crosses a cacheline or page boundary) is quite fast on i5/i7 cores.  (Note that aligned access is still faster, so you should always make sure that at least one of your accesses is aligned; it's just that when you're reading from multiple arrays, you should generally align those you can and use misaligned access on the others now instead of trying to do something more clever).

Comment: Just to offer some concrete numbers, from the Intel optimization manual, on i7 for data in L1 cache: misaligned loads that do not cross a cacheline boundary are exactly as fast as aligned loads (single-cycle throughput), and misaligned loads that do cross a cacheline boundary take about 4 cycles (compare to ~20 cycles on earlier microarchitectures).

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that when you find a mismatch within a larger chunk, you must then identify the first differing `char` *within* that chunk so that you can calculate the correct return value (`memcmp()` returns the difference of the first differing bytes, treated as `unsigned char` values).

Answer (score 1):

If you compare as int, you will need to check alignment and check if count is divisible by sizeof(int) (to compare the last bytes as char).

Answer (score 1):

Is that really their implementation? I have other issues besides not doing it int-wise:

- castng away constness.
- does that return statement work? unsigned char - unsigned char = signed int?

int at a time only works if the pointers are aligned, or if you can read a few bytes from the front of each and they are both still aligned, so if both are 1 before the alignment boundary you can read one char of each then go int-at-a-time, but if they are aligned differently eg one is aligned and one is not, there is no way to do this.

memcmp is at its most inefficient (i.e. it takes the longest) when they do actually compare (it has to go to the end) and the data is long.

I would not write my own but if you are going to be comparing large portions of data you could do things like ensure alignment and even pad the ends, then do word-at-a-time, if you want.

Comment: The "casting away constness" is only to allow the incrementing of the pointer by `char` sized chunks. That is also what's going on in the return statement -- the `char` versions aren't being dereferenced and compared, they are simply undergoing pointer subtraction. Also keep in mind w.r.t. the `const` ness that this `memcmp` was probably written before `const` was added to the language, and someone just tacked on `const` to the method signature to update it for C++. EDIT: Also, you really didn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Billy there is no need to cast away constness you just create const char* pointers locally then use them throughout, and can increment them too. And yes, I did answer the OP's question, stating about the possible issues with alignment if you compared word-at-a-time which is what he proposed.

Comment: There certainly is reason to cast away `const` ness if the code is written before `const` exists. I see that you sort of do answer the question now, but it's buried inside your bashing of one particular implementation to the point that I didn't see it.

Comment: `unsigned char - unsigned char = int` is exactly what's required, and yes, it does work.  There's an implicit promotion of arithmetic arguments narrower than `int` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to optimize for the processor cache and fetching.  Processors like to fetch in large chunks rather than individual bytes at random times.  Although the internal workings may already account for this, it would be a good exercise anyway.  Always profile to determine the most efficient solution.

Psuedo code:

```
while bytes remaining > (cache size) / 2 do // Half the cache for source, other for dest.
  fetch source bytes
  fetch destination bytes
  perform comparison using fetched bytes
end-while
perform byte by byte comparison for remainder.
```

For more information, search the web for "Data Driven Design" and "data oriented programming".

Some processors, such as the ARM family, allow for conditional execution of instructions (in 32-bit, non-thumb) mode.  The processor fetches the instructions but will only execute them if the conditions are satisfied.  In this case, try rephrasing the comparison in terms of boolean assignments.  This may also reduce the number of branches taken, which improves performance.

See also *loop unrolling*.
See also *assembly language*.

You can gain a lot of performance by tailoring the algorithm to a specific processor, but loose in the portability area.

Answer (score 1):

The code you found is just a debug implementation of `memcmp`, it's optimized for simplicity and readability, not for performance.

The intrinsic compiler implementation is platform specific and smart enough to generate processor instructions that compare dwords or qwords (depending on the target architecture) at once whenever possible.
Also, an intrinsic implementation may return immediately if both buffers have the same address `(buf1 == buf2)`. This check is also missing in the debug implementation.

Finally, even when you know exactly on which platform you'll be running, the perfect implementation is still the less generic one as it depends on a bunch of different factors that are specific to the rest of your program:

- What is the minumum guaranteed buffer alignment?
- Can you read any padding bytes past the end of a buffer without triggering an access violation?
- May the buffer parameters be identical?
- May the buffer size be 0?
- Do you only need to compare buffer contents for equality? Or do you also need to know which one is larger (return value < 0 or > 0)?
- ...

If performace is a concern, I suggest writing the comparison routine in assembly. Most compilers give you an option to see the assembly lising that they generate for a source. You could take that code and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Many processors implement this as a single instruction. If you can guarantee the processor you're running on it can be implemented with a single line of inline assembler.

Comment: Just because it's a single assembly op doesn't mean it's faster! x86 string operations are _slow_ as they expand to a large number of micro-ops out of a slow instruction decode ROM